# Running the CUDA command line profiler programmatically

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda, command, profiler, nvidia

How do I programmatically launch a CUDA command line app under the CUDA profiler and access the generated profiling information stored as .csv files by the profiler?

Background:

I'm writing a program that automates performance comparisons between CPU and GPU versions of equivalent codes. The program takes the paths to two executable files as arguments, one for the CPU and one for the GPU. The program then profiles the GPU version by running it under the CUDA command line profiler and analyses the results.

I'm using Windows 7.

I would like to launch the profiler by using the system() or ShellExecute() call.

I have to tried to run it like this: system("nvvp + filepath")

I have read the Compute Command Line Profiler User guide, but have not found the required information there.

Comment: i just want to get some data on how efficient is application written under GPU compared to CPU. Any tips are welcome.

Comment: I won't post this as an answer, but... For expert users (which I don't think the OP is), the CUDA Profiling Tools Interface (CUPTI) library can be used to build advanced profiling behavior into applications. See the CUPTI User's guide included with the CUDA Toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

To sum up the comments, the answer is basically that you shouldn't launch the profiler programmatically. You would end up with invalid comparison results and the profiler does not provide metrics such as memory usage.

Instead, keep track of memory usage within the applications, launch them with regular system calls and time them with [Windows timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644900%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: it's like that: i'm writting a program which after running take two exe files(one is written under CPU and the other one is written under CUDA-they make exact same thing and i want to compare performance) pointed by user. And the program itself runs profiler and generates cvs file, or any other type of file in which are contained informations about performance(time of execution, memory etc.)

Comment: I took the liberty of rewriting your question. Please check if it still represents what you want to know and edit if necessary. One potential flaw for your planned app is that the profiler can slow down the CUDA app, so that the comparison to the CPU version is no longer valid. To compare the two versions, your app should run the GPU version outside of the profiler and time both in the same way.

Comment: Thx, for rewriting, english is not my native language. Ok, so i'll run my app outside the profiler with system("nvcc -run filepath"); how to get the time of running or other resources, that the program have used?

Comment: Is there any need to compile your app and run it in the same step? If not, just build your CUDA app the normal way, inside Visual Studio. Then launch it with a plain `system(path);` command in your comparison app. Time the calls by using a [Windows timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644900%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Which other resources would you need to compare?

Comment: Memory used, i have to compare IPP with NPP, and Thrust with STL mainly. All important differences in performance. any other sugestion are welcome:D